# how to index specific cell in the table

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to get  value from specific cell like row =3 , column= 2 I tried .get but it doesn't work

```
import tkinter as tk

app = tk.Tk()


class Excel(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, rows, columns, width):
        super().__init__(master)

        for i in range(columns):
            self.make_entry(0, i + 1, width, f'C', True)

        for row in range(rows):
            self.make_entry(row + 1, 0, 5, f'R{row}', True)

            for column in range(columns):
                self.make_entry(row + 1, column + 1, width, '', True)

    def make_entry(self, row, column, width, text, state):
        e = tk.Entry(self, width=width)
        if text: e.insert(0, text)
        e['state'] = tk.NORMAL if state else tk.DISABLED
        e.coords = (row - 1, column - 1)
        e.grid(row=row, column=column)

r=3
ex = Excel(app, rows=r, columns=10, width=8)
ex.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

ex2 = Excel(app, rows=3, columns=5, width=20)
ex2.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You say you tried, but I see no code that tries to do that. Also, what does "doesn't work" mean? Does it get the wrong value? Does it do nothing? Does it throw an error, and if so, what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get` however it helps to keep a collection of the `Entry`'s so that you can find it. Presently you just abandon `e` each time and rely on tkinter to keep a track of it.

Alternatively, you can make the form event driven so that your code only runs on change. To do this, register a validate function.

```
        e = tk.Entry(self, width=width,
                     validate='focusout',
                     validatecommand=(self.register(self.validate), '%P', row,
                                      column))
```

And define the validation function. I added row and column to the `validatecommand` tuple to provide an indication of where it came from.

```
    def validate(self, value, row, column):
        print(value, row, column)
```